# Docker run rabbitmq -e RABBITMQ_SSL_CERT=/path/to/cert/file

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, dockerfile

I am new to docker. I am trying to run rabbitmq image with ssl configuration. From [this](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/pull/49) I found I need to pass the path to the cert file as environment variables. My question is the path to cert files is a path on local? or should it be a path on rabbitmq?

Comment: Skimming through the changeset at https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/pull/49/commits/a86f48150ccfa05c7334e750f430b348d958f34d at least the running instance of the container needs 1) as you do already the environment variable `RABBITMQ_SSL_CERT=/path/to/cert/file` and 2) access from the container to this path (as common sense and no special rabbitmq docker knowledge whispers me.

Comment: @Dilettant : The container is not able to access these path.

Comment: Why not simply run the official RMQ image, or one with management plugin, and just copy over the certificates and rabbitmq.config? How to generate the certificates as well as the appropriate rabbitmq.config can be found here https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html. Litreally just copy over everything and execute. Also here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/ how to copy from host to container

Comment: @cantSleepNow : That's what I am using. To enable the ssl for that image the docker_entrypoint.sh requires  RABBITMQ_SSL_CERT and 2 more variables. https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/pull/49

Comment: @user3527975 What I meant is that use docker image, and copy the generated pem files and rabbitmq.config to it. Btw, this is the official RMQ docker image https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/

Comment: @cantSleepNow: Ok. I knew I could copy the certificates. But I do not know how to make rabbitmq use them.

Comment: Did you look into direct mounting of volumes to make them accessible/usable via `-v <host_dir>:<container_dir>`

Comment: @Dilettant: Yes. I was able to mount volume on rabbitmq. Do you know how can I test it if it's actually using the ssl files?